# Techniques on how to stochastic optimize.

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, stochastic-analysis

I am looking to collect stochastic optimization techniques to find a solution to the following problem

\begin{eqnarray*}
  &\text{maximize}\,\, \mathbb{E}(u(f(B)))\\
  &\text{subject to }\,\,\, g_t(B)\geq 0, t\in[0,T]
\end{eqnarray*}
where $B$ is a random variable belonging to the nonnegative random variables, $f$ depends on $B$, $g$ is a function that depends on $t,B$ and $u$ is a convex function. I have read some results,  but all of them cover cases where the constraint is static ($g(B)\geq0$ for instance), but not in this dynamic context. If someone knows of any results, such as papers or books that discuss this type of problem, I would appreciate it if you could provide me with that information. Thank you!.

Comment: Why would the solution to this be non-degenerate?  I would expect $B$ to just be equal to the constant that solves the deterministic version of this problem.

Comment: You're right; I forgot to mention that $B$ belongs to the set of non-negative random variables. The problem involves optimizing over this set. I apologize for the oversight; it has been corrected now. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Adding an additional constraint doesn't really address what I'm saying.  My point is, if we have a deterministic constant $x \ge 0$ that maximizes $u(f(x))$ and satisfies $g_t(x) \ge 0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$, the optimal random variable $B$ should just be $B=x$.  If that optimal deterministic constant doesn't exist, then the optimal random variable probably doesn't exist either.

Comment: I get it now. You're right. Maybe there is no solution that exists. I am looking for information on how to resolve this kind of problem. Under which conditions is there a solution? For instance, in the case that $g$ does not depend on $t$, I have found some results, but in this case, I found nothing. Like when the problem is deterministic, it could be solved by Lagrange multipliers. Thank you for your comments.